# How to send a token other then eth with metamask without extension of course?

Tags: web3js, tokens, metamask

I wanted send token other than eth with metamask using code but I did a little bit of research couldnt find anything. Do you guys know anything about that? I checked metamask docs site too didnt find anything in there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming this question is about sending ERC20 tokens, programmatically.

For that, you would need the following things.

1. The private key of the account from which you will send the tokens. (you'll find this in your metamask itself).
2. The token contract address.
3. The receiver's address.

You can use any library, but I'll suggest ethers js.

Here is a step-by-step guide for this.
https://community.infura.io/t/ethers-js-how-to-send-erc-20-tokens/6721

Comment: I dont like ethers but will try thx